# Sort array of strings which may containing day and abbreviated month names

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, natural-sort

I want to sort an array in an ascending direction, but a normal sort approach will not respect the optionally occurring day and month substrings.  The strings containing "Feedback" must be sorted by month then day as they appear on the calendar.

Not even `natsort()` will respect the months as I require.

Example array:

```
$array = [
    "Feedback 13 okt",
    "Feedback 11 okt",
    "Feedback 12 okt",
    "Sweet",
    "Feedback 9 okt",
    "Feedback 6 okt",
    "Feedback 8 jun",
    "Fixes",
    "Realisation",
    "Feedback 22 mar",
    "Do something",
    "Feedback 3 maj",
    "Feedback 1 dec",
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    'Do something',
    'Feedback 22 mar',
    'Feedback 3 maj',
    'Feedback 8 jun',
    'Feedback 6 okt',
    'Feedback 9 okt',
    'Feedback 11 okt',
    'Feedback 12 okt',
    'Feedback 13 okt',
    'Feedback 1 dec',
    'Fixes',
    'Realisation',
    'Sweet',
]
```

Comment: the solution is to strip out the numbers so that you can use any sort function and pass it a clean argument to sort as you please.

Comment: 8 > 6  no! when php encounters a number it sorts by it,the feedback string is the same so it starts to order by the numbers

Comment: Well I don't want it to order on the numbers, I want for it to focus on the 'okt', 'jun' before the numbers

Comment: @Calimero That could work

Comment: Can we see some code? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have just tried some sort functions ( sort, natsort and some others), they don't do what I want though. I have a foreach that pushes all the results into this array (((foreach ($item['description'] as $key => $row)
        {
            array_push($description, $row);
        }))). I want to order everything accordingly first and then I will push this into an other array. I've only really tried some sorting functions, but I can't seem to find a solution on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to implement your own comparison function which first compares two strings without any numbers (use [preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $str)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg_replace.php) for this), and then, if the two strings compared as equal, use [strnatcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) to compare the strings (including numbers) in a [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) way.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $cmp = strcmp(preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $a), preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $b));
    if ($cmp) {
        return $cmp;
    } else {
        return strnatcmp($a, $b);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `DateTime` from the date part and sort the dated entries chronologically in `usort`. I was not able to get my locale settings right to work with your language so I had to edit the data to use English month abbreviations. I assume you have your PHP properly configured for your locale so this should work on your system with your data.

```php
usort($array, function($a, $b) { 
  $pattern = '/^\w*\s+/'; // ("Feedback ") matches first word + whitespaces
  $fmt = 'j M';
  $a_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($fmt, preg_replace($pattern, '', $a));
  $b_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($fmt, preg_replace($pattern, '', $b));
  if($a_date && $b_date) // both are dates
    return $a_date <=> $b_date;
  // fallback to compare as strings
  return strcmp($a, $b);
});
```

So with the following `$array` value:

```php
$array = [
    "Feedback 13 oct",
    "Feedback 11 oct",
    "Feedback 12 oct",
    "Sweet",
    "Feedback 9 oct",
    "Feedback 6 oct",
    "Feedback 8 jun",
    "Fixes",
    "Realisation",
    "Feedback 22 mar",
    "Do something",
    "Feedback 3 may",
    "Feedback 1 dec",
];
```

After calling the `usort` function above `var_export($array);`  will output the following:

```php
array (
  0 => 'Do something',
  1 => 'Feedback 22 mar',
  2 => 'Feedback 3 may',
  3 => 'Feedback 8 jun',
  4 => 'Feedback 6 oct',
  5 => 'Feedback 9 oct',
  6 => 'Feedback 11 oct',
  7 => 'Feedback 12 oct',
  8 => 'Feedback 13 oct',
  9 => 'Feedback 1 dec',
  10 => 'Fixes',
  11 => 'Realisation',
  12 => 'Sweet',
)
```

See it working here: https://onlinephp.io/c/dc5d6

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, it seems my interpretation of the required sorting logic is more in-depth than the asker's.

I see the rules as:

1. Sort by the first word, then if a tie,
2. If a "Feedback..." string, then parse the string and sort by month, then by day, then if still a tie,
3. Sort on the full string "naturally" and case-insensitively.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eLVLf))

```
$array = [
    "Feedback 13 okt",
    "Feedback 11 okt",
    "Feedback 12 okt",
    "Sweet",
    "Feedback 9 okt",
    "Feedback 6 okt",
    "Feedback 8 jun",
    "Fixes",
    "Realisation",
    "Feedback 22 mar",
    "Do something",
    "Feedback 3 maj",
    "Feedback 1 dec",
];

$mmm = array_flip([
    "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr",
    "maj", "jun", "jul", "aug",
    "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"
]);

usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        strtok($a, ' ') <=> strtok($b, ' ')

        ?: (sscanf($a, "Feedback %d %s", $aDay, $aMon)
            ? [$mmm[$aMon] ?? 13, $aDay]
            : [13, 32])
           <=>
           (sscanf($b, "Feedback %d %s", $bDay, $bMon)
            ? [$mmm[$bMon] ?? 13, $bDay]
            : [13, 32])

        ?: natcasecmp($a, $b)
);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Do something',
  1 => 'Feedback 22 mar',
  2 => 'Feedback 3 maj',
  3 => 'Feedback 8 jun',
  4 => 'Feedback 6 okt',
  5 => 'Feedback 9 okt',
  6 => 'Feedback 11 okt',
  7 => 'Feedback 12 okt',
  8 => 'Feedback 13 okt',
  9 => 'Feedback 1 dec',
  10 => 'Fixes',
  11 => 'Realisation',
  12 => 'Sweet',
)
```

By using the "Elvis operator" (`?:`), subsequent tiebreaker processes are only executed if necessary.  This is best practice and offers best performance.

---

Alternate syntax for the above approach leveraging the `$mmm` lookup array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2hrZK))

```
usort(
    $array,
    function($a, $b) use($mmm) {
        sscanf("$a 32 dec", "%[^0-9] %d %s", $aWord, $aDay, $aMon);
        sscanf("$b 32 dec", "%[^0-9] %d %s", $bWord, $bDay, $bMon);
        return [$aWord, $mmm[$aMon], $aDay] <=> [$bWord, $mmm[$bMon], $bDay];
    }
);
```

---

If comfortable with regex, make a single pass over the array to make a modified version of the strings which can be sorted naturally (again leveraging the `$mmm` lookup array).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DOOfc))

```
array_multisort(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/(.+) (\d+?) ([a-z]{3}?)/',
        fn($m) => "{$m[1]} {$mmm[$m[3]]} {$m[2]}",
        $array
    ),
    SORT_NATURAL,
    $array
);
```